# How to render LaTeX / HTML in Jupyter (R)?

Tags: html, xml, r, jupyter

I just started using Jupyter with R, and I'm wondering if there's a good way to display HTML or LaTeX output.

Here's some example code that I wish worked:

```
library(xtable)
x <- runif(500, 1, 50)
y <- x + runif(500, -5, 5)
model <- lm(y~x)
print(xtable(model), type = 'html')
```

Instead of rendering the HTML, it just displays it as plaintext. Is there any way to change that behavior?

Comment: your code does not displays plain text but html code. Please so clarify your question.

Comment: Right - it displays the HTML code as plaintext, instead of rendering it as an HTML table.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A combination of `repr` (for setting options) and `IRdisplay` will work for HTML. Others may know about latex.

```
# Cell 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------

library(xtable)
library(IRdisplay)
library(repr)

data(tli)
tli.table <- xtable(tli[1:20, ])
digits(tli.table) <- matrix( 0:4, nrow = 20, ncol = ncol(tli)+1 )

options(repr.vector.quote=FALSE)

display_html(paste(capture.output(print(head(tli.table), type = 'html')), collapse="", sep=""))


# Cell 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------

display_html("<span style='color:red; float:right'>hello</span>")

# Cell 3 ------------------------------------------------------------------

display_markdown("[this](http://google.com)")

# Cell 4 ------------------------------------------------------------------

display_png(file="shovel-512.png")

# Cell 5 ------------------------------------------------------------------

display_html("<table style='width:20%;border:1px solid blue'><tr><td style='text-align:right'>cell 1</td></tr></table>")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found a simpler answer, for the initial, simple use case.

If you call xtable without wrapping it in a call to print, then it totally works. E.g.,

```
library(xtable)
data(cars)
model <- lm(speed ~ ., data = cars)
xtable(model)
```

Comment: This works because xtable returns an object of class  `"xtable", "data.frame"` and the display system (repr/IRdisplay) which in place in irkernel converts to html.

Answer (score 2):

In Jupyter, you can use Markdown. Just be sure to change the Jupyter cell from a code cell to a Markdown cell. Once you have done this you can simply place a double dollar sign ("$$") before and after the LaTex you have. Then run the cell.

The steps are as follows:
 1. Create a Markdown cell.
 2. $$ some LaTex $$
 3. Press play button within Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Defining the following function in the session will display objects returned by xtable as html generated by xtable:

```
repr_html.xtable <- function(obj, ...){
    paste(capture.output(print(obj, type = 'html')), collapse="", sep="")
}

library(xtable)
data(cars)
model <- lm(speed ~ ., data = cars)
xtable(model)
```

Without the `repr_html.xtable` function, because the returned object is also of class `data.frame`,  the display system in the kernel will rich display that object (=html table) via `repr::repr_html.data.frame`.

Just don't `print(...)` the object :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Render/Embed html/Latex table to IR Kernel jupyter

**Some packages in R give tables in html format like "knitr", so if you want to put this tables in the notebook:**

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(IRdisplay) #the package that you need

#we create the table
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
options(knitr.table.format = "html") 
html_table= kable(dt) %>%
kable_styling("striped") %>%
add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2" = 2, "Group 3" = 2))

#We put the table in our notebook
display_html(toString(html_table))
```

Or for example if you have a file

```
display_latex(file = "your file path")
```