# Hiding code in jupiter in R

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I would like to try to produce reports (pdf and probably html) in jupyter using R kernel. However, I would like to hide code in two ways, depending on audience:

1. all code cells
2. some code cells

When I have looked for this I found answers for python kernel. Is there a way to this in R (no python code)?

Answer (score 9):

So I have started to combine python's answer:
[How to hide code from cells in ipython notebook visualized with nbviewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934885/how-to-hide-code-from-cells-in-ipython-notebook-visualized-with-nbviewer)
with 
[How to render LaTeX / HTML in Jupyter (R)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703654/how-to-render-latex-html-in-jupyter-r/32717083#32717083)
and it works. 
If one puts the following code in a cell, will get a button for hiding code. From here I think I know where to start.

```
library(IRdisplay)

display_html(
'<script>  
code_show=true; 
function code_toggle() {
  if (code_show){
    $(\'div.input\').hide();
  } else {
    $(\'div.input\').show();
  }
  code_show = !code_show
}  
$( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
  <form action="javascript:code_toggle()">
    <input type="submit" value="Click here to toggle on/off the raw code.">
 </form>'
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This allows me to give html exported notebooks to people rather than having to mess with markdown!

Comment: Adaptation for JupyterLab: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617446/the-function-display-html-not-working-in-jupyter-lab/71937773#71937773

Answer (score 2):

As you're talking about making HTML and PDF reports, you can do this by using a custom template with nbconvert, and using that to hide cells. This will work for any notebook, independent of the kernel you use.

Docs on nbconvert templates: http://nbconvert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html

Examples including hiding code cells based on cell metadata: https://github.com/jupyter/ngcm-tutorial/tree/master/Day-2/nbconvert_templates

Answer (score 0):

Add some `CSS` code in the first cell, change that cell to 'Raw NBConvert' and the format specified in the `CSS` will be applied to the HTML generated:

To hide input blocks:

```
<style type="text/css">
.input_hidden{
    display: none
}
</style>
```

Other style definition can also go there.

Then run `ipython nbconvert the_name_of_the_stuff.ipynb --to slides` to generate the HTML (without the input blocks).