# Return an output in the markdown of a Jupyter lab notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, markdown

This is the code:

```
# State with most Zip code
    x <- df3 %>% count(state) %>% 
           arrange(desc(n)) 

     x[1,]
```

it returns

```
state   n
Texas   1935
```

My markdown is:

> The state which has the most zip code is **`x[1,1]`** with a total of **`x[1,2]`** zip codes.

but what I would like is the markdown to say:

> The state which has the most zip code is **Texas** with a total of **1935** zip codes automatically based on my output x.

I tried all sort of combination of tick marks and `{{...}}` but to no avails...

Comment: Last I knew this is a place where R markdown use inside RStudio, see [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_intro.html), is better suited for what you describe. [This discussion](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/inline-variable-insertion-in-markdown/10525?u=fomightez) will probably be of interest to you. However, most of it focuses on the ipykernel-based notebooks and not the irkernel-based notebooks. Likewise, in ipykernel-based notebooks you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32035217/8508004) to have Python code that makes markdown in output cells. I don't know the R ...

Comment: <continued> equivalent, sadly. I refer to that code and the Python Markdown extension [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-add-markdown-inside-a-function-to-pretty-print-equation/2719/2?u=fomightez). I don't know of the irkernel equivalent of that extension though. UPDATE: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35786496/8508004) references code that "This perfectly does the job of printing Markdown inside a code cell." So that may be a lead. (I think it means [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32717083/8508004)?)